# Listings package: How to highlight math operators?

Tags: listings, highlighting

I am using the listings package to include GAUSS code to Latex.

E.g. like this:

```
\lstset{
emph={proc,retp,endp,local}, emphstyle=\color{blue}\textbf,
emph={[2]=,.^,./,=}, emphstyle={[2]\color{red}}
}

\begin{lstlisting}
proc(1) = tdist(n,v);
local x, z, z2, u, t;
x=rndn(n,1); 
z=rndn(n,v);
z2=z.^2; 
t=x./((U./v)^(1/2));
retp(t);
endp;
\end{lstlisting}
```

While the strings (proc, retp etc.) are highlighted, the math operators (=, *, /) are not. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't do this with the `emph` key.  But you can do it using the `literate` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\lstset{
emph={proc,retp,endp,local}, emphstyle={\color{blue}\textbf},
literate={./}{{{\color{red}./}}}2 {.^}{{{\color{red}.\^{}}}}2 {=}{{{\color{red}=}}}1
}

\begin{lstlisting}
proc(1) = tdist(n,v);
local x, z, z2, u, t;
x=rndn(n,1); 
z=rndn(n,v);
z2=z.^2; 
t=x./((U./v)^(1/2));
retp(t);
endp;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Note that all the braces are required, since you need to limit the scope of the `\color` command.

[image: output of code]

Comment: This works quite fine with a low number of characters but fails for whole words regarding spacing. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277486

Comment: The problem is that the definition of colors is mixed with the definition of the language.  I would normally prefer to define the syntactic categories in a package, but choose/customize colors in the document I am typesetting.  This solution does not help :(

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add some observations to Alan's answer, since I also ran into that issue, landed here and I see your question is only partially answered.

If you want operators like `/` or `*` coloured, too, you might get in trouble with comments in code. As `literate` will break the way comments will be recognized by the `listings` package. Here is an example:

```
/** 
 * This is a 
 * comment ...
 **/
let java = s / c + r * i - p + t    // and this is some code
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot0]

Now you want to highlight `/` and `*` in the equation, but it breaks the commets:

```
literate=%
  {+}{{{\color{Red}+}}}1
  {-}{{{\color{Red}-}}}1
  {*}{{{\color{Red}*}}}1
  {/}{{{\color{Red}/}}}1
  {=}{{{\color{Red}=}}}1
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot1]

Obviously, the comments both are broken. Now I played around with adding spaces to the pattern, but with insufficient results.

```
literate=%
  {\ +}{{{\color{Red}\ +}}}1
  {\ -}{{{\color{Red}\ -}}}1
  {\ *}{{{\color{Red}\ *}}}1
  {\ /}{{{\color{Red}\ /}}}1
  {\ =}{{{\color{Red}\ =}}}1
```

The block comment is now recognized, but the one-line comment not.

[image: Screenshot2]

So, why not appending a whitespace, too?

```
literate=%
  {\ +\ }{{{\color{Red}\ +\ }}}1
  {\ -\ }{{{\color{Red}\ -\ }}}1
  {\ *\ }{{{\color{Red}\ *\ }}}1
  {\ /\ }{{{\color{Red}\ /\ }}}1
  {\ =\ }{{{\color{Red}\ =\ }}}1
```

This is the closest I could get to the desired result.

[image: Screenshot3]

You can see it somehow shrinks the whitespaces. Some could dive into [the dozens of different TeX whitespaces from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/14076). But you'll get an idea.